# Execute jquery in if statement

Tags: php, jquery, if-statement

I got a login system, and what I want to do is to hide a div and show another div when the user types the incorrect login details. However it doesn't seem to work.

```
if(...) { // here I check if the user enters the correct information

... //much code inside

} else { // if incorrect info, do this
    echo "<script>$('#jqueryhide2').hide();
        $('#jqueryhide').show();</script>";
}
```

Tried to google a bit but can't find anything that could solve my problem.

Comment: Why don't you use if statement for printing divs in proper place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
put this code and also include your Jquery file -(dont forget)
echo "<script>
$('document').ready(function(){ 
$('#jqueryhide2').hide();
$('#jqueryhide').show();
});</script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the script tags inside your statement. You can simply do the following. ( Make sure jqueryhide and jqueryhide2 are a part of the DOM. )

```
if (blah == blah )
{
    $('#jqueryhide2').show();
    $('#jqueryhide').hide();
}
else
{
    $('#jqueryhide2').hide();
    $('#jqueryhide').show();
}
```

Comment: Would work **if** the if-else clausel weren't part of a PHP script.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois: Did you mean "Woudn't" ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should missing the Onclick function like this:

```
<script>
$('loginId').Onclick(function(){ 
$('#jqueryhide2').hide();
$('#jqueryhide').show();
});</script>";
```